# How to find the closest parent directory that distinguishes duplicated file names?

Tags: r, path

I have a list of full pathnames and I would like to return the path from the nearest parent directory that de-duplicates the file paths.

Here is an example of what I have (I have grouped duplicated files on the same lines):

```r
have <- c("/A/B/C/D", "/A/B/D", "/A/C/D",
          "/path/to/unique_file",
          "/path/to/another_unique_file",
          "/path/diverges/here/file", "/path/diverges/here1/file")
```

And what I am trying to get:

```r
want <- c("B/C/D", "B/D", "A/C/D",
          "unique_file",
          "another_unique_file",
          "here/file", "here1/file")

> length(unique(want)) == length(have)
[1] TRUE
```

A few parameters:

1. In this example, I have 3 `D`, 2 `file`, 1 `unique_file`, and 1 `another_unique_file`, but in my actual problem there could be any number of duplicated file names.
2. At the very least, the entire pathname will be unique (as you might expect). It is okay to return the full pathname if that is the shortest (from the right) unique path. `/A/B/C/D` would make the first file distinct, but `B/C/D` also makes it distinct and is shorter, which is what I need.
3. As shown with the first set of filenames, files with the same name can be nested at different depths. For example, `D` is in the third, second, and second subdirectory, respectively.
4. My preference is to use base R functions, unless there is a package that makes this algorithm simpler to read and much shorter to code.

---

It is easy to group them using `split`:

```r
> split(have, basename(have))
$another_unique_file
[1] "/path/to/another_unique_file"

$D
[1] "/A/B/C/D" "/A/B/D"   "/A/C/D"  

$file
[1] "/path/diverges/here/file"  "/path/diverges/here1/file"

$unique_file
[1] "/path/to/unique_file"
```

From here I am hoping to get some help working backwards from the filenames until the paths are unique. I had considered a recursive function, but I am not sure that will work with the different depths.

Comment: Most file systems allow multiple ways to specify each file, e.g. , `./foo` vs `foo` on most file systems, case differences on some.  Are you assuming that the filenames have passed through `normalizePath()` already?

Comment: I don't understand your rules.  Why doesn't the answer start `c("C/D", "B/D", ...`?

Comment: @user2554330 `C/D` would be a duplicate of the third element which also ends with `C/D`. You need to go up one more directory to make it unique. All pathnames will be of the format `/<folder name>/<folder name>/<file name>`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a non-recursive method.  It works by starting at the end, and looking for duplicate tails.  Once a tail is unique, include it in the result.

```r
have <- c("/A/B/C/D", "/A/B/D", "/A/C/D",
          "/path/to/unique_file",
          "/path/to/another_unique_file",
          "/path/diverges/here/file", "/path/diverges/here1/file")

# This isn't necessary from your description, but it might be 
# a good idea
have <- normalizePath(have, mustWork = FALSE)

# Split each path
splits <- strsplit(have, "/", fixed=TRUE)

# Reverse each path, dropping the initial empty entry
revsplits <- lapply(splits, function(x) rev(x[-1]))

# Find the length of each
lens <- sapply(revsplits, length)

# Assume all are duplicates to start
dup <- rep(TRUE, length(have))

# Initialize the results with NA to signal not done yet
result <- rep(NA, length(have))

# Loop through from last entry to first entry
for (i in seq_len(max(lens))) {
  entry <- sapply(revsplits, function(s) s[i])
  
  # It's a dup if not already non-dup, and this entry is duplicated
  dup <- dup & (duplicated(entry) | duplicated(entry, fromLast = TRUE))
  
  # If we have any new non-dups, record them
  done <- is.na(result) & !dup
  if (any(done))
    result[done] <- sapply(revsplits[done], function(x) paste(rev(x[1:i]), collapse = "/"))
  
  # If all are done, quit
  if (all(!dup)) break
}

# If any are left just copy them
result[dup] <- have[dup]

result
#> [1] "B/C/D"               "B/D"                 "/A/C/D"             
#> [4] "unique_file"         "another_unique_file" "here/file"          
#> [7] "here1/file"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You could use a recursive approach, with one subroutine to find the unique paths, and another to extract and format them. These can both be wrapped in a single function:

```r
unique_filenames <- function(filepaths) {
  
  split_paths <- function(filepaths) {
    subgroups <- split(dirname(filepaths), basename(filepaths))
    clash <- lengths(subgroups) > 1
    if(any(clash)) subgroups[clash] <- lapply(subgroups[clash], split_paths)
    return(subgroups)
  }
  
  read_list <- function(li) {
    final <- !sapply(li, is.list)
    li[final] <- names(li)[final]
    if(any(final)) {
      li[!final] <- Map(\(x, nm) {
        names(x) <- paste(names(x), nm, sep = "/")
        read_list(x)
      }, li[!final], names(li)[!final])
    }
    return(unlist(unname(li)))
  }
  
  read_list(split_paths(filepaths))
}
```

Testing, we have

```r
unique_filenames(have)
#> [1] "another_unique_file" "B/D"                 "A/C/D"              
#> [4] "B/C/D"               "here/file"           "here1/file"         
#> [7] "unique_file"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your post! A follow up question about your logic: should `if (any(final))` be `if (any(!final))`? I am not clear why it should be the former since those instance are already settled with `li[final] <- names(li)[final]`.